# amazon s3 secret key, access Key and object key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new in aws, and gone through documents of s3 as well but, I always get confused on one thing.
What is the actual difference among the secret key, access key and object key in amazon s3.

Would be grateful to know,Thanks in advance.

Comment: I couldn't find anything on secret keys, but did find [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/wheres-my-secret-access-key/) on secret access keys.  The object key is just the key pointing to your object in S3.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Thanks,
I am generating signed Url using 
new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objectKey), it's asking for object key, what do i actually need to provide there ?

Answer (score -1):

1. Access keys consist of an access key ID (for example, AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE) and a secret access key (for example, wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY).
2. You use access keys to sign programmatic requests that you make to AWS if you use the AWS SDKs, REST, or Query API operations. The AWS SDKs use your access keys to sign requests for you, so that you don't have to handle the signing process. You can also sign requests manually. For more information, see Signing AWS API Requests.

**Important**

- Do not provide your access keys to a third party, even to help find your canonical user ID. By doing this, you might give someone full access to your account.
- Access keys are also used with command line interfaces (CLIs). When you use a CLI, the commands that you issue are signed by your access keys. You can pass access keys either with the command or store as configuration settings on your computer.
- You can also create and use temporary access keys, known as temporary security credentials. In addition to the access key ID and secret access key, temporary security credentials include a security token that you must send to AWS when you use temporary security credentials. The advantage of temporary security credentials is that they are short term. After they expire, they're no longer valid. You can use temporary access keys in less secure environments or distribute them to grant users temporary access to resources in your AWS account. For example, you can grant entities from other AWS accounts access to resources in your AWS account (cross-account access). You can also grant users who don't have AWS security credentials access to resources in your AWS account (federation). For more information, see Temporary Security Credentials in the IAM User Guide. For information on the unique IDs that IAM creates, including their prefixes (like the AKIA used in AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE, above), see IAM Identifiers in the IAM User Guide.
- You can have a maximum of two access keys (active or inactive) at a time. For your AWS (root) account, see Managing Access Keys for Your AWS Account. For IAM users, you can create IAM access keys with the IAM console. For more information, see Creating, Modifying, and Viewing Access Keys (AWS Management Console) in the IAM User Guide.
- If you or your IAM users forget or lose the secret access key, you can create a new access key.

Reference: [Understanding and Getting Your Security Credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html#access-keys-and-secret-access-keys)

Comment: I am generating signed Url using new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objectKey), it's asking for object key, what do i  actually need to provide there ?

Comment: Object key will be your S3 Object full URL lile: <bucketname>/<folder>/s3_objectname

Comment: @Chintan7027 incorrect.  The object key does not include the bucket name or a leading slash.  It's `path/to/my/image.png`.

Comment: Think of `Key` = `Filename` (including the full path from the root of the bucket)